# How to check simple connectivity in graph?

Tags: c#, graph, nodes

I have this adjacency matrix :

[image]

And I don't know if I can check if any of the nodes are not connected with the others. I mean, if it's alone, a row and column of zeros (for example, the first one, `A`,) should return false because simple connectivity does not exist.

```
public bool HayConectividadsimple()
    {
        bool respuesta = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Aristas.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Aristas.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i, j == 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Hope you can help me.

Best regards,

Comment: This depends on what type of object Aristas actually is. If it's a 2D array, then presumably you just need to do `Aristas[i,j]` there? Unless you're looking for the whole column to be 0 - if so, return false? P.s. Post your actual code rather than a screenshot as that will save someone from having to write it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I post it the code instead screenshot and yes I'm looking for the whole column of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you're looking for a whole row of 0 and a whole column of 0. If you spot either then return false. Roughly something like this:

For each node..

1. check if it has an all 0 column
2. Check if it has an all 0 row
3. If both are true, return false

Return true otherwise.

So, that looks like this:

```
public bool HayConectividadsimple()
{

    // For each node..
    for (int i = 0; i < Aristas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        // Assume it's not connected unless shown otherwise.
        bool nodeIsConnected=false;

        // Check the column and row at the same time:
        for (int j = 0; j < Aristas.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (Aristas[i, j] != 0 || Aristas[j, i] != 0)
            {
                // It was non-zero; must have at least one connection.
                nodeIsConnected=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Is the current node connected?
        if(!nodeIsConnected)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // All ok otherwise:
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Awesome !